# scanf("%f",&aa) VS scanf("%f",&aa) in a while loop

Tags: c, char, scanf

**I use the program below to calculate the absolute value of a number that I write. The program should stop when `aa` becomes `n`.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float a;
char ap;
printf("Start? Press n for no.\n");
scanf("%c",&ap);
while(ap!='n'){
  printf("Give a number\n");
  scanf("%f",&a);
    if(a<0){
    a=-a;
    }
  printf("Abs=%f\n",a);
  printf("Continue? Press n for no.\n");
  scanf("%c",&aa);
}
printf("Exit");
return 0;    
}
```

**The program seems to ignore `scanf("%c",&aa)` in the `while` loop and that's my problem.** *Italics* are input **bold** are output:

> **Start? Press n for no.**
>
> *y*
>
> **Give a number**
>
> *4*
>
> **Abs=4.000000**
>
> **Continue? Pres n for no.**
>
> **Give a number**
>
> *5*
>
> **Abs=5.000000**
>
> **Continue? Pres n for no.**
>
> **Give a number**
>
> *n*
>
> **Abs=5.000000**
>
> **Continue? Pres n for no.**
>
> **Exit**

The problem is solved when I replace `scanf("%c",&aa)` with `scanf(" %c",&aa)` (see the space). Also, everything is ok when `aa` is a number. The program works fine and it stops when `aa` becomes `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float a, aa;
printf("Start? Press 0 for no.\n");
scanf("%f",&aa);
while(aa!=0){
  printf("Give a number\n");
  scanf("%f",&a);
    if(a<0){
    a=-a;
    }
  printf("Abs=%f\n",a);
  printf("Continue? Pres 0 for no.\n");
  scanf("%f",&aa);
}
printf("Exit");
return 0;
}
```

What is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space before `%c` **removes any white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines)**. It means `%c` **without space will read white space like new line(\n), spaces(‘  ‘) or tabs(\t).** By adding space before `%c`, we are `skipping` this and reading only the char given.

Comment: But `scanf("%c",&aa)` is after the newline `\n`. Why is it reading this?

Comment: The scanf() function skips leading whitespace automatically before trying to parse conversions other than characters. The character formats (primarily %c; also scan sets %[…] — and %n) are the exception; they don't skip whitespace.

Comment: I think I understand... Thanks a lot!